# Issue with using hashicorp's memberlist on two different computers

Tags: go, hashicorp, gossip

i have a problem

I have made a program that uses hashicorp's memberlist gossip protocol, to connect between clients and send data. When i am running two clients on the same computer, it works just fine. But for some reason, when i am connecting to the server from a different computer, it doesnt work. I get these logs on both machines:

```
2023/09/25 12:22:04 [DEBUG] memberlist: Failed UDP ping: 1 (timeout reached)       
2023/09/25 12:22:05 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect 1 has failed, no acks received      
2023/09/25 12:22:06 [DEBUG] memberlist: Failed UDP ping: 1 (timeout reached)       
2023/09/25 12:22:08 [INFO] memberlist: Marking 1 as failed, suspect timeout reached (0 peer confirmations)
2023/09/25 12:22:08 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect 1 has failed, no acks received
```

Also, if i create the memberlist from the computer im joining now, i get i/o timeout error.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this error?

**Thank you**